# Using XP With different wifi profiles switched by SSID, not by User

Tags: windows-xp, ssid, wifi-configuration

My Office Laptop is set to receive an IP address using DHCP, when connected over WiFi. This works fine at the office (ssid:corpnet) and at home (ssid:homenet)!

I often commute to a client, where I've been issued a static Ip, for use with their WiFi (ssid:other)... is there any way I can tell XP to configure the IP settings by itself based on the ssid?

My Mac & iPad work that way... so that's where I got the idea.

Comment: Unless you use a program to handle treat the connections as profiles, the simplest workaround, would be a .bat script you run that changes the configuration for you.

Comment: I already have the bat scripts, that is a working solution ... but I was getting lazy/forgetfull ... thus hoping for convenience & automation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like [**NetSetMan Pro**](http://www.netsetman.com/index.php?s=help)'s [**AutoSwitch**](http://www.netsetman.com/index.php?s=help&hf=en#hf_autoswitch) feature might help:

[image: 1]

> It's easy to activate a profile with one click from the tray menu. But in some cases it's necessary to always activate a certain profile at a certain location. Then even one click might feel like too much effort.
>
> NetSetMan AutoSwitch is the solution! AutoSwitch recognizes your location analyzing WiFi networks nearby. All you have to do is connecting one or more WiFi networks with any of your NetSetMan profiles. As soon as those networks are in range AutoSwitch will automatically launch the profile activation. A notification will show up as a countdown with a predefined delay allowing you to abort the activation process if you like.

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

There are some limitations in XP though, so be sure to read the documentation thoroughly first.

Comment: Thanks @Karan. I looked at the  NetSetMan page you link above. Since I DO use the machine to earn money, I'd need to buy the pro license (20 Euro, ca. 25$). That's 100% fine with me .. but I'll be looking at other options first.